# What mime types are plain text?

Tags: javascript, mime-types

I'm writing a small Javascript function that gives out a preview of a file if its content can be inserted into a `div.innerText`, so I'm looking for all text-based mime types. For example, I know that `text/*` all satisfy this requirement, but there's also `application/json` for example. Is there a comprehensive list of such types?

Comment: The complete list can be found [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). Which of them you will want to consider as plain text is your choice.

Comment: What about just looking at the the encoding?

Comment: @toddmo Well the idea is, given the mime type, I want to tell whether I should actually poll for more data from this file to display it in the preview, so I can't look at the encoding without actually copying the whole file from the server.

Comment: @yelsayed You could make a HEAD request to check the encoding (header) without fetching the full file

Comment: I would just start your white list and log every unknown type (not on either white or black list) . Inspect the log periodically and build up the white and black list. You'll get very high coverage in short order.

Comment: @yelsayed is `application/javascript` or `application/json` "readable"? Take someone who is not related to programming and show him/her a compacted JS- or json-file and a jpeg file in some text editor. What do you think, would he/she consider one of them "readable", or be able to tell them apart? It's up to you to **define what you consider readable**. Who's your audiance? What is the purpose of your application? What would your audiance expect of you to support? And what would be a "nice to have"? These are the questions you should ask yourself.

Comment: @Thomas To me there's a natural distinction between files that are meant to be opened in a text editor, and ones that are not, but it seems there might not be wide agreement on the significance of that.

Comment: Yes, files that are meant to be opened in a text-editor are defined by their mime-type as text: `text/*`. Then there are other files that can be opened in a text-editor and can be "read" by people who can read them. You seem to include various source-files in that category. I'd also add pdf, jpeg and mp3, because they also contain stuff I can "read" in plain text. But I doubt that even most of the SO-users here would "agree" with me on that and call these types readable. Or how about svg? That's exactly my point. Who is your audiance, and what would they consider readable?

Comment: @Thomas I fully agree. Of course the OP wants to distinguish between formats that use a string of printable characters as their encoding of data and those formats that don't but encode it in binary sequences, but something like SVG (or SVGZ or base64-encoded SVG) is a prime example of a file that falls in all categories: binary, text, graphics, code, markup…

Comment: I get your point, it looks to me like I need to collect my own white list then. I was hoping this would have been a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

This seems to fit what you're asking for :)

Extra, quick rundown of what each category achieves: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types

Comment: Not really, this is a list of all mime types. The very first one, `.aac` for example, seems like a binary file type. I can't display that as text.

Comment: Take a look at the extra bit, that may be more suited to your needs in that case. That first link though does provide all text based mime types, unless you need them as one list to provide to your code?

Comment: Nope. I gave the example of `application/json` specifically for this case. `application/*` should be used for all application specific files, binary or not.

Comment: My mistake then! Sorry